Is there a way to ensure a function is called for every instance of a subclass inheriting from a base class?
OptionsAndAnswer is the base class.
abstract class OptionsAndAnswer(
    ...,
    open val options: List<Option>
){
    fun validate() {
        require(options.map { it.id }.distinct().size == options.size) {
            "all option ids should be unique"
        }
    }
}

The validate method is explicity called in the it's subclasses init method i.e.
data class StringOptionsAndAnswer(
    ...,
    override val options: List<StringOption>
): OptionsAndAnswer(answerId, options) {
    init { validate() }
}

Is there a way to call the validate method in the base class OptionsAndAnswer, such that all sub classes inherit that validation?
putting the logic in OptionsAndAnswer's init method results in a NullPointerException as OptionsAndAnswer.init is called before StringOptionsAndAnswer.init.

If your goal is to just avoid writing a init { validate() } in every subclass, you can make options abstract in the superclass, and change the primary constructor to take a simple parameter instead of a val.
abstract class OptionsAndAnswer(
    options: List<Option>
) {
    abstract val options: List<Option>
    init {
        validate(options)
    }

    private fun validate(options: List<Option>) { ... }
}
data class StringOptionsAndAnswer(
    override val options: List<StringOption>
): OptionsAndAnswer(options)

This way, you can validate the argument passed into the constructor, instead of the open property.
Of course, this validation can be simply bypassed by doing:
data class EvilOptionsAndAnswer(
    override val options: List<Option>
): OptionsAndAnswer(listOf())

So if your goal is to enforce this validation, this won't work.
